# R Shiny: test data in reactive environment

Tags: r, shiny

I am rewriting an already existing code into a shiny app. The code includes several if-statements similar to the following example:

```
dataPrep = eventReactive(input$execute, {
  inputdata = data()$dat
  analyse = reshape()$analyse
  x = reshape()$x
  y = reshape()$y
  z = reshape()$z

  if((analyse[3]==1 & dim(inputdata)[[2]]>(length(c(x,y,z))+1)) |
       (analyse[3]==0 & dim(inputdata)[[2]]>(length(c(x,y))+1)) )
  {
    if (sum(dimnames(inputdata)[[2]]=="int")==1)
    {
      if (analyse[3]==1)
      {
        inputdata.short <- inputdata[,c("num",x,y,z)]
      }
      if (analyse[3]==0)
      {
        inputdata.short <- inputdata[,c("num",x,y)]
      }
    }
    if (sum(dimnames(inputdata)[[2]]=="INT")==1)
    {
      if (analyse[3]==1)
      {
        inputdata.short <- inputdata[,c("NUM",x,y,z)]
      }
      if (analyse[3]==0)
      {
        inputdata.short <- inputdata[,c("NUM",x,y)]
      }
    }
  }else
  {
    inputdata.short <- inputdata
  }

  inputdata.short[is.na(inputdata.short)] <- 0
})
```

This causes again the error

> Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero

In addition there the console shows an error saying

> eventReactiveHandler .../path

Is there an efficient way to adjust the code? Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: Is anyone there who knows how to handle this issue? Would be very grateful for help. Thanks